# locate and click, a portion of image inside another image

Tags: python, image, opencv, pyautogui, locate

I have a image1 which I locate with pyautogui, center and click.
It is ok.

But I have portion of this image to click, once I locate the first and I m not able to get coordinates to click.

I find out CV2 module, and I was able to match template with image, but I m not able to get TEMPLATE coordinates once I GOT the first image.

so basically I have image1, which i locate, and there is a portion of image2, called template, which i need to locate.

I need do this, because, first image can change position on screen. How i get x, y to center the template image?

```
pyautogui.position ( x, y , 1 )
```

this is the script which work matching image with template

the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import pyautogui as p

img_rgb = cv2.imread('big.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('portion.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
##print (w,h)
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_gray, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 2)
##cv2.imshow('Detected',template)
#( of course before this I will center the x and y with locate / center somehow )
p.moveTo (x of portion , y of portion ,1) #( of course before this I will center the x and y with locate / center somehow )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I did it.
I just locate the first image. Then I locate the second giving first image coordinates as region ti check.
It was simple.
Sorry guys bother u.